# Warning:Field XXX doesn't have a default value

Tags: python, sql

I get this error on the script below:

```
Warning:Field 'HUN2' doesn't have a default value.

cmd, pars = """INSERT INTO USERS_WORDS (USERID, WORDID, SUBTITLEID, CONTEXT, TIMESTAMP, DATE) SELECT * FROM (SELECT %s,
    %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT USERID, WORDID FROM USERS_WORDS
    WHERE USERID=%s AND WORDID=%s) LIMIT 1""", (userid, wordid, subtitleid, context, timestamp, date, userid, wordid)

try:
cursor.execute(cmd, pars)  //The error points to this line
db.commit()
```

In the above statement I don't insert any values in the HUN2 field so why do I get this error?
Note: The field is varchar(50), has no default value and I don't think I should set any.

Comment: If there's no default value and you do not set any value explicitly, what do you expect that value to be?

Comment: Should I set '' as default value, or NULL, or should I insert '' into the field?

Comment: Can you describe your table USERS_WORDS ?

Answer (score 0):

As Vincent has mentioned in his comment, the table needs a value or the lack thereof for the 'HUN2' column. Either ways, it needs to stated either explicitly or implicitly :

> 1. If you have a value to insert for that particular column, insert it. If you don't have a value (*for this particular record*) then you
>      need to state that explicitly (by inserting a `NULL` value).
> 2. If the value of 'HUN2' is most likely to be a particular value for most records or atleast to begin with, (*but, might change
>      thereafter*), then you might set that value as default.

This aforementioned particular value can be an actual value or the lack thereof (`NULL`). That is, NULL itself can be set as the default value.

Based on business rules, you can decide which of the two options mentioned above you'd like to go with.

Hope this helps!!!